# How to pass exception message from DLL to main application

Tags: c#, exception, dll, share

Let's say that I have a class in my dll file:

```
public ClassInDllFile()
{
    String str = "";
    try
    {
        str = someClassMethod();
    }
    catch (Exception e) // or more precised exception type
    {
        // some code
    }
}
```

I don't want to put exception message in MessageBox from Dll level (it requires additional references), but I would to pass it to some (on example) WinForm application.

Comment: Actually I didn't try yet (lack of ideas), but I will write some code snippets now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just catch the exception in the WinForms class.

This means you should not catch the exception here, but in the WinForms class itself, where you can show a dialog.

You could use something like (I changed a bit of code from your example to improve naming):

```
public ClassInDllFile()
{
    # Other functions

    ///
    /// Might throw a ... exception
    ///
    public Run()
    {
        String str = someClassMethod(); # Might cause an exception

        # More code
    }
```

And in your WinForms class:

```
var instance = ClassInDllFile()
try
{
    instance.Run()
}
catch (Exception e) // or more precised exception type
{
    // Error handling code
}

# More code
```

Also it is a good idea to document the ClassInDllFile.Run function which type of exceptions it might generate to inform calling functions to act upon it.

Comment: Looks cool, but messy if I would have to catch one of 4 exceptions. Anyway thanks, I think that .NET does not support other way :)

Comment: Normally you should catch the exception (only) at the level where you want to handle it. 

If you have an exception that should be handled at WinForms 'level', you should catch that particular exception there. If you have an exception that can be handled in the DLL, than that exception should be catched in the DLL.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways in which you could handle this.

One simple way is to just throw the exception, and handle it in the outer / calling class.

Another is to gather info from the exception in your `catch` clause (like ExceptionMessage, StackTrace, and perhaps `InternalException`), and store these in properties that the the calling class can check. You might then also include a boolean property like `Suceeded`, which you set to `false` if an exception occurs. Then the calling class can check that property after making the call, and retrieve more details about the exception if it needs them.

You can manipulate this however you want. Experiment until you find a solution that fits your needs.

Comment: Can i create a static class in Dll which will contain bool var like ExceptionOccured with details and share it between main application? It would require additional Thread / Event / etc. (but I think this would be the only way). I mean I should use a thread or event for this?

Comment: Not sure I follow you here. I don't think you need an extra thread or anything fancy. Just store the info somewhere where the main application can fetch it, itself. Do this in the `catch` clause, before you return control to the main application, and you will know that the status is correct when the main application checks it. PS: Creating events for this would be like reinventing exception-logic; in that case, you would probably be better off just throwing the exception back out, and handling int in the main app.